# Blender to Unity, UV Map is messy in Blender and in Unity

Tags: materials, uv

im New to Blender since i was using Cinema4D all the time,

i´ve done a Medieval House out of 5 different Textures, i baked them together into one Texture 4096 by 4096,

now i deleted all materials which were attached to my Blender Model, i Created a new Material and i attached the UV Map to it,

in Objekt Mode it looks fine:
[image]

in Render Mode my Model looks Messy i dont know why, i hope someone can help me.

[image]

Blend file
[image]

Baked texture
[image]

Comment: Edit , problem found! I had 2 UV Tags on my Model x)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I expected. You have two UV maps. The one called UVW is messed up and ruins your render. Take a look at the screenshot below. You either need to get rid of UVW map (indicated by red area) or plug in the correct UV map into your image texture node (indicated by blue area). Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5966" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5966/)

Comment: and the texture: https://www.pic-upload.de/view-36373288/House01-Bake.png.html

Comment: Please use comments for blend / image requests.  Have edited links above into question. Recommend deleting answer to avoid the down-voters.